# FindAsync not finding results with DateTime comparison

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
    using MongoDB.Bson;
  
    public async Task<List<Person>> Get(string lastName, string firstName, string dob, string id)
    {
        var dobParse = DateTime.Parse(dob);

        var persons = await _patients.FindAsync<Patient>(person => 
            (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName) || person.lastName == lastName) &&
            (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName) || person.firstName == firstName) &&
            (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dob) || person.dob.Equals(DateTime.Parse(dob))) &&
            (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) || person.Id == id));

        return await persons.ToListAsync();
    }
```

When isolated it looks like all other comparisons work as they return results, except for this condtion `(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dob) || person.dob.Equals(DateTime.Parse(dob)))`. I've tried various ways of checking for a null dob DateTime including passing it in as a nullable DateTime and checking if it has value, as well as various ways of comparing the 2 DateTime objects.

Here is a sample record and parameters used to query it:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "610f727c7ec433f528bf3727"
  },
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "dob": "1980-01-30T00:00:00"
}

QueryParams: lastName=Doe&firstName=John&dob=1980-01-30T00:00:00&id=610f727c7ec433f528bf3727
```

The DateTimes are identical.

I've added some debug code to compare the DateTimes and added setting the search DateTime kind to UTC and adding the UTC attribute to the model property for "Person".

```
public async Task<List<Person>> Get(string lastName, string firstName, string dob, string id)
{
    var dobParse = DateTime.Parse(dob,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

    var Persons = await _Persons.FindAsync<Person>(person => 
        (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName) || person.lastName == lastName) &&
        (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName) || person.firstName == firstName) &&
        //person.dob == dobParse &&
        (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) || person.Id == id));

    var resultDob = Persons.FirstOrDefault().dob;

    if (dobParse == resultDob)
    {
        var match = true;
    }

    return await Persons.ToListAsync();
}
```

In the example above `match` is set as true as `if (dobParse == resultDob)` resolves as true. However, no results from the DB are still returned despite the other conditions being true (firstName, lastName, and id).

Comment: Do you have an example date in the DB that does not match your given string?

Comment: Questions like this are usually a failure to appreciate that datetimes go all the way down to milliseconds and that 12:34:56 is not the same as 12:34:56.000001, especially if whatever db viewer app/debugger you use doesn't include the milliseconds part

Comment: It might be better to match a range, rather than an Exact date as @CaiusJard Mentioned.  On another note, Make sure your string date format is consistent.

Comment: You can verify if its a format issue by using `ParseExact` instead of `Parse`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have updated the question with a sample record and related query for that record. The query is not returning anything even with the same exact DateTime with precision to the millisecond.